# Numberformat Exception in parseInt

Tags: java

I tried this code and get an exception, could anyone help. The value passed to the function is "12" even then, I get exception. I tried with/without trim etc.,

public class TestClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String line = "12-10-1984";
    String [] temp = line.split("-");
    String t1 = temp[0].trim();
    Integer.parseInt(t1);
    }catch (Exception e){
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Oh those characters aren't what you think they are.

Comment: "1�2�-�1�0�-�1�9�8�4";
IS this really your string?

Comment: I don't think that *is* really the asker's string, but was introduced in an edit; see comments on one of the answers below. Removed. user3135635, please check me on that.

Comment: I rolled it back to original, just not to mess with anything.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta If you open up edit now, you don't see the characters?

Comment: Well, isn't that weird. I see the characters if I click the edit link above, but not if I click the edit link from the revision page. @Sotirios, care to give that a shot?

Comment: (Though I think mike's edit may have caused a race condition there)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Same as you from revision. I see the characters when editing directly from OP.

Comment: I have removed those special characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could try filtering your string like this...

```
String[] temp = line.split("-");
String t1 = temp[0].trim();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch : t1.toCharArray()) {
  if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
    sb.append(ch);
  }
}
if (sb.toString().length() > 0) {
  int v = Integer.valueOf(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get it, I tried it and got this result "This character('') is not a digit and when cast to an int has a value of 0". I am not sure why it is not recognizing 12

Comment: Thanks this works. If possible, could you please explain the need for this approach, why it didn't directly recognize the string

Comment: There are `nulls` (that is '\0' characters) in your String.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your "-" in both these lines does not match.
You can print the value of t1 and check if it is returning "12".

This might happen when you copy the string from a screen having different charset eg: Word/Outlook.

Comment: No I didn't. I just typed that date.

Comment: what is the value of 't1' ?